# FineUploader not working after first upload

Tags: reactjs, fine-uploader

I've implemented FineUploader in my React app to upload files to my Azure Blob Storage and it's working fine except for one issue.

After uploading a file successfully, if I try uploading another one, FineUploader is not allowing me to select a new file. Clicking the select button opens up the dialog box to let me select a file but clicking the file to select it simply does nothing. I don't see any errors either.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Here's my implementation of FineUploader in my app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import FineUploaderAzure from 'fine-uploader-wrappers/azure'

// Components
import Gallery from './gallery/index';

// Actions
import * as fileActions from '../../../../actions/file-actions';

// Instanciate FineUploader
const uploader = new FineUploaderAzure({
    options: {
        cors: {
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials: false
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: 'https://api.myapp.com/files/get/sas'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container'
        },
        validation: {
            itemLimit: 1
        }
    }
})

class FileUploader extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.saveFileInfo = this.saveFileInfo.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        uploader.on('complete', (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) => {

            const originalName = uploader.methods.getName(id);
            const blobName = uploader.methods.getBlobName(id);
            const fileSize = uploader.methods.getSize(id);

            this.saveFileInfo(originalName, blobName, fileSize);
        })
    }

    saveFileInfo(fileName, blobName, fileSize) {

        // Gather necessary information
        const accountId = this.props.accountId;
        const id = this.props.id;
        const folderId = this.props.activeFolder.id;
        const files = [
            {
                fileName: blobName,
                displayName: fileName,
                fileSize: fileSize
            }
        ];

        // Call backend API to save file info in database
        this.props.actions.createFileRecords(accountId, bizObject, id, privilegeLevel, folderId, files);

        // Close modal
        const modalId = this.props.modalId;
        return this.props.handleClose(modalId, false);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div style={{ position: 'fixed', zIndex: 250000990 }}>
                <div className="modal-wrapper">
                    <div className="height-100 width-100" style={{ background: 'transparent', position: 'absolute', left: '0', top: '0' }}></div>
                    <div className="modal-window vertical-center">
                        <div className="modal-controls padding-right-20 padding-top-10" style={{ height: '50px', position: 'absolute', right: '0', top: '0', lineHeight: '40px', borderColor: 'transparent !important' }}>
                            <a className="modal-control mc-help"></a>
                            <a className="modal-control mc-close" onClick={e => this.props.handleClose(this.props.modalId, false)}></a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="width-100 height-100 border-radius border-black-w1-1" style={{ overflow: 'hidden', background: 'black !important', borderColor: 'black' }}>
                            <Gallery uploader={uploader} onComplete={this.handleFileUpload} />
                        </div>
                        <div style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: '17px', left: '17px' }}>

                            {/* Privilege Level Selector */}
                            {this.renderPrivilegeLevels()}
                            <span className="app-btn app-btn-lg margin-left-20">Uploading into Folder: <strong>{this.props.activeFolder.name}</strong></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {

    return {
        modalId: ownProps.modalId,
        accountId: ownProps.accountId,
        id: ownProps.id,
        folders: ownProps.folders,
        activeFolder: ownProps.activeFolder,
        fileUpload: state.files.fileUpload,
        errors: state.files.errors,
        handleClose: ownProps.handleClose
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {

    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(fileActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FileUploader)
```

Comment: Looks like your example could be reduced some more. Providing a [mcve] makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: Silly question, but are you trying to upload the same file twice?

Comment: @Bigga_HD No, I’m trying to upload other files

Comment: @Sam can you please try to remove the `itemLimit`? I've checked the GitHub project's issues and it seems to have some weird behavior related to the limits. If removing the limits resolves the issue, then in order to have the limits, you can try to reinitialize the plugin after the first successful upload. That approach is taken from the GitHub issues.

Comment: @Sam what are you trying to achieve with itemLimit? Because that option is to limit the number of file to upload in the same Uploader Instance (exactly your issue). Removing it would allow you to select any number of file.
Maybe you want to prevent multiple file at once?

Comment: @Zeromus I want to prevent users from uploading multiple files at a time but want users to be able to upload a second or third file after uploading the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comment the `itemLimit: 1` option is limiting the total number of upload for that `Uploader` to 1.

Since what you are trying to achieve is actually avoiding multiple upload at once you can use the option [`multiple: false`](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#multiple) to block selection of multiple files.

Also, to avoid users adding more files while others are still uploading, you can use a custom validation where you check if some other files are in [progress](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getInProgress), for example:

```
   options: {
      ..., //other options
      callbacks: {
         onValidate: function (file) {
           if(getInProgress() > 0){
              return false;
           }        
           return true;        
      }
   }
```

Note that the [onValidate](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#validate) events is called before the default Fine Uploader validators